Is there a non-trivial, convex, increasing sequence of prime numbers whose sum of reciprocals diverges?
A sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of integers is called convex if $a_{n+1} - a_{n} \geq a_{n} - a_{n-1}.$
Is there a non-trivial (i.e. non-constant), convex, increasing sequence of prime numbers whose sum of reciprocals diverges?
The Green-Tao theorem means we can get long strings of prime arithmetic progressions, but making use of this seems difficult.
At a cursory glance at a list of prime numbers, I would suspect that the answer is negative.

If I didn't say non-trivial then constant sequences like $(2,2,2,2,...)$ would be an affirmative answer.

Conjecturally the answer is no. We expect that when $x$ is sufficiently large, there is a gap between primes up to $x$ of size at least $(\log x)^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha>0$ (indeed we even think we can take $\alpha=2$). If that were true, then a convex sequence of primes could contain at most $ex/(\log x)^\alpha$ elements between $x$ and $ex$, and the sum of their reciprocals would be $\ll 1/(\log x)^\alpha$. Summing over intervals of the form $[e^kx,e^{k+1}x)$ would yield an upper bound of the form
$$
\ll \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{(\log e^kx)^\alpha} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^\alpha}
$$
which converges.
An elaboration of this argument, using intervals like $[x,x^e)$ instead of $[x,ex)$, shows that the answer is still no even if we can only guarantee prime gaps below $x$ as large as $(\log x)(\log\log x)^\alpha$ for some $\alpha>1$. However, the largest known prime gaps today (due to Ford, Green, Konyagin, Maynard, and Tao) are just a bit less than $(\log x)(\log\log x)$, which isn't quite enough for this argument to work.
